# msbuild fails with type or namespace name missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a C# project (csproj) and a solution (sln), which I want to build via `msbuild.exe`.

```
$ msbuild.exe foo.sln /m /t:Build /p:Configuration="Release"
```

This fails with several errors like these here:

```
(CoreCompile target) ->
     AppComboCommand.cs(9,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'EnvDTE' could not be found
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [foo.csproj]
```

These errors go away after I opened the project in Visual Studio 2019 and then build again through command line again. VS seems to generate a few files while opening the project, and I am wondering what I miss here. Is this maybe a dependency problem?

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: `EnvDTE` is it a library? if yes how you added it to the project?

Comment: EnvDTE seems to be a microsoft/c#/system dependency?

Comment: Hi Daniel, any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

**EnvDTE** is just a vs sdk dll for extend visual studio functionality and it is usually stored in the vs local folder.

First, you should make sure that you have installed the `Visual Studio extension development` workloads first. If you use Build Tool for VS2019, you should also remember to check it.

[image]

Please follow these:

**1)** If you reference this dll in the local area, please make sure that you have referenced it by Right-click on project-->`Add Reference`-->reference `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\envdte.dll`.

- **This below approach** is not recommended, and for vs SDK DLL references, using nuget is risky：

  If you use nuget to install it the `EnvDTE` which does exist in `nuget.org`, when you build it from command line, you should run `nuget restore MySolution.sln` first. MSBuild Command line will not restore the missing packages and it is not its job.

So please download [nuget.exe](https://www.nuget.org/downloads) first and then add this in script:

```
$nuget="xxxxx\nuget.exe(the local path of the nuget.exe)"

$nuget restore `xxxxx\MySolution.sln`
```

Then execute the build process.

**2)** I found that you use a powershell script to build the project, so please make sure that you use MSBuild for VS2019 not the one of Net Framework(`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe`).

```
$msbuild.exe="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe"
```

If you install **Build Tool for VS2019**, you should use this path:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe`

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer! But do I need to download nuget? As said, after I opened the solution in VS, the command line works. What does VS do on startup what I could also trigger manually? And why does msbuild.exe does not do that? Btw, VS Extension Kit is installed.

Comment: And when I added EnvDTE through "Add Reference" it tells me this is automatically added through the build system, so I actually can't select it

Comment: Please make sure use MSBuild.exe for VS2019 not msbuild.exe from framework.